# Creating universal UDF that executes in the calling db context

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm aware that you can create a stored procedure in master and use 'sp_MS_marksystemobject' and then call the sp from any database and it will run in the local db context.  I've tried to do the same with a UDF and that doesn't seem to work.

- I've tried creating a synonym to the function but that causes the function to execute in the master database.
- I've executed 'sp_MS_marksystemobject' against the function but when I call it with [master].[dbo].[myfunction], it executes in the master db.
- Calling the function with just [dbo].[myfunction] and it can't find the UDF.

So how can I create a universal function that I can call from any database and have it run in the local context of the calling DB?

Comment: Check this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122890/user-defined-function-udf-in-master-database
That functionality works only with stored procedures.

Comment: create a clr udf,which accepts connection string as one of the parameters

Comment: MS recommend you avoid using the SP_ prefix: *Avoid the use of the sp_ prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name.*   [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql).